# Phalcon dispatcher forwarding having no effect

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a component configured as a `beforeDispatch` listener.  This component checks if a form was POSTed, then checks that the CSRF token was properly sent.  If not, it's supposed to forward to a special CSRF notification page.  I specifically want to do a forward and not a redirect, so that users have the option of reporting which page they visited.

Here is my code:

```
public function beforeDispatch(\Phalcon\Events\Event $Event,\Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher $Dispatcher){
    if($this->request->isPost()){
        if(!$this->checkToken()){
            echo 'before';
            $Dispatcher->forward(['controller'=>'index','action'=>'csrf']);
            echo 'after';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

All I get is a page that displays "beforeafter".  If I take those `echo`s out, I just get a blank page.  I can visit `/index/csrf/` manually and it displays the page I want.

Why is the request not getting forwarded?  Is this out of the dispatch loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have coded:

```
exit();
```

?

I'm not sure you can use forward here has the dispatcher does not yet know if the controller and action exist yet in the dispatch loop. https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/dispatcher#dispatch-loop

But I think you can intercept and control what the controller class and action the dispatcher should execute using.

```
$dispatcher->setModuleName(<your module nam if you have one>);
$dispatcher->setNamespaceName(<your controller class>);
$dispatcher->setActionName(<your action name>);
```

Check the docs on [dispatch loop](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/dispatcher#dispatch-loop)

Comment: I exit() after the forward, so the forwarded action should still get executed.  I added the code you suggested (plus `setControllerName()`), and I get an error: "Action 'index' was not found on handler 'users'" - I'm setting the controller name as 'index' and the action name as 'csrf', so I don't understand the error.

Comment: Removing `exit()`, and adding a condition to not forward if I'm already at the CSRF action, has fixed the problem.  I guess `forward()` and `exit()` don't work like I assumed.